# Merge rows and values in R based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following sample data:

```
# data
school = c('ABC University','ABC Uni','DFG University','DFG U')
applicant = c(2000,3100,210,2000)
students = c(100,2000,300,4000)
df = data.frame(school,applicant,students)
```

I want to merge to this:

```
|school        |appliant| students |
-----------------------------------
|ABC University| 5100   | 2100     |
|DFG University| 2210   | 4300     |
```

I ran this code:

```
df$school[df$school == 'ABC Uni'] = 'ABC University'
```

But it gives me ABC University twice instead of merging them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the rest of your strings, but you could take a look into `grep` and use `^` for begins with.

```
df[grep('^ABC U', df$school), 'school'] <- 'ABC University'
df[grep('^DFG U', df$school), 'school'] <- 'DFG University'
```

And the `aggregate` as usual.

```
aggregate(cbind(applicant, students) ~ school, df, sum)
#           school applicant students
# 1 ABC University      5100     2100
# 2 DFG University      2210     4300
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `dplyr` `stringr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(school = str_replace_all(school, c(
        "^ABC Uni$" = "ABC University",
        "^DFG U$" = "DFG University"))) %>% 
    group_by(school) %>% 
    summarise(across(c(applicant, students), sum))
```

output:

```
  school         applicant students
  <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ABC University      5100     2100
2 DFG University      2210     4300
```